# List Comprehension creates too many levels of nested lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I am combining elements on two lists together, but the element that gets pulled in is itself a sublist. How can I just make it item[2] of the list?

My Code:

```
list =  [["pineapple", 10], ["cherry", 20], ["Carrot", 13], ["plum", 12]]
list1 = [["pineapple", 'Fruit'], ["cherry", 'Fruit'],["Carrot", 'Vegetable'],["plum", 'Fruit'],["Pepper", 'Vegetable']]

list = [[v1[0], v1[1], [v2[1] for v2 in list1 if v2[0] == v1[0]]] for v1 in list]

print list
```

My Output:

```
[['pineapple', 10, ['Fruit']], ['cherry', 20, ['Fruit']], ['Carrot', 13, ['Vegetable']], ['plum', 12, ['Fruit']]]
```

Desired Output:

```
[['pineapple', 10, 'Fruit'], ['cherry', 20, 'Fruit'], ['Carrot', 13, 'Vegetable'], ['plum', 12, 'Fruit']]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see the relationship between the two lists. Could you not just go through `list1` and repeat element `[0]` twice? Also do not use `list` as a variable name

Comment: I am trying to grab `item[3]` from `list1` to append it to `list1`. thanks for the note about list naming. I don't use it my actual code, just for stack overflow example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just add an index accessor to that inner list comprehension, so you get the first element of that list instead of the whole list:

```
#                                                     This part is new
#                                                            ↓↓↓
>>> [[v1[0], v1[1], [v2[1] for v2 in list1 if v2[0] == v1[0]][0]] for v1 in list]
[['pineapple', 10, 'Fruit'], ['cherry', 20, 'Fruit'], ['Carrot', 13, 'Vegetable'], ['plum', 12, 'Fruit']]
```

Since you are basically looking up the fruit categories, you could make `list1` into a dictionary. This allows you to—well—just look up a value, without having to iterate through the whole list:

```
# to convert the existing `list1`
>>> categories = dict(list1)

# or specify it directly as a dictionary:
>>> categories = {'pineapple': 'Fruit', 'cherry': 'Fruit', 'Carrot': 'Vegetable', 'plum': 'Fruit', 'Pepper': 'Vegetable'}
```

Then you can just use the index to look up a category. For example `categories['pineapple']` gives you `'Fruit'`. So you can use that in your list comprehension:

```
>>> [[v1[0], v1[1], categories[v1[0]]] for v1 in list]
[['pineapple', 10, 'Fruit'], ['cherry', 20, 'Fruit'], ['Carrot', 13, 'Vegetable'], ['plum', 12, 'Fruit']]
```

Finally, one note: You shouldn’t name your variables just `list`. First of all, `list` is the built-in variable that references the list type, and overwriting the value of that variable can cause a lot of confusion later. Second, and that’s actually more important, such variable names give you zero information about their content. It’s better if you name then appropriately so you know what they contain and what they are used for.

Comment: This is a great explanation, but can you comment as to why using a dictionary is better than storing the values in the list of list?

Comment: Look at how you were looking up the value from that list. You kept iterating it every time for each value you wanted to look up. Now, a dictionary in contrast is built in a way so that the lookup is very efficient. When you want to look up something, you can do that in constant time, without having to iterate through the whole dictionary. So it’s a lot more efficient—and if you look at the usage, it’s also a lot more clear what’s going on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dictionaries to make this list comprehension easier:

```
numbers = dict(list)
types = dict(list1)
result = {key:[numbers[key], types[key]] for key in numbers.keys()}
```

Note: 
This will only work "types" has all keys of "numbers".